# Al seleccionar un elemento del select, que me aparezca la función que busco

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Estoy trabajando en un nodo de node-red y me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para que al seleccionar un elemento del `select`, por ejemplo "Range of days", y que abajo se me muestre solo el `div` que me engloba a ese `input`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto mi html:

```
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option selected> Choose one: </option>
        <option value="day">Day</option>
        <option value="range">Range of days</option>
        <option value="week">Week</option>
        <option value="month">Month</option>
      </select>


    <div class="container">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Choose a day:
        <input id="node-input-calendar" type="date" name="calendar" style="width: 30%;">
        <label for="calendar"></label>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Choose a range of days:
        <input id="node-input-calendarRange" type="date" name="calendar" style="width: 30%;"> to <input id="node-input-calendarRangeTwo" type="date" name="calendar" style="width: 30%;">
        <label for="calendarRange"></label>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Choose a week:
        <input id="node-input-week" type="week" name="calendar" style="width: 35%;">
        <label for="week"></label>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Choose a month:
        <input id="node-input-month" type="month" name="calendar" style="width: 35%;">
        <label for="calendar"></label>
    </div>
```

Disculpad si hay errores, muchas gracias.

Comment: Estaría faltando el código `Javascript` que has intentado. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregarlo?

Comment: Buenas Marcos, de momento no había añadido js, porque no sabía cual era la forma más eficiente de hacer esto que pido. Un saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sencilla de hacerlo es con JavaScript, también el atributo **id** en tus elementos `select` y `div` contenedores de cada sección.

Para el caso del `select` puede ser:

```
<select class="form-select" id="dates" aria-label="Default select example">
```

Para cada div además de la clase contenedor:

```
<div class="container" id="range">
```

Adicional antes de cerrar la etiqueta body agregas el código JS, ten en cuenta que todos los elementos con la clase container se ocultarán al seleccionar una opción, por lo que si tienes más elementos que no tienen que ver con esta funcionalidad, debes agregar una clase adicional a cada div que quieras que se oculte.

```
<script>
    const selectElement = document.querySelector('#dates');
    
    selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

        var x = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display= "none";
        }

        document.querySelector("#"+event.target.value).style.display = 'block';
    });

</script>
```